# jQuery one() handler executed twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, animate.css

I have a bug in my jQuery/`animate.css` code. The problem is an event handler that is called twice but it should be executed only one. You can find the code here, the important line is below:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uhz6Ly0s/7/)

```
$('#tiles').addClass(tiles_in).one(animation_end, function() {
    // called twice
    log('tiles in');
});
```

In order to reproduce the bug, follow these steps:

- Wait for the animation to end, which will output these logs

  - `change_tiles`
  - `tiles out`
  - `tiles in`
- Click on the yellow `div`, here are the new logs

  - `tile out // normal`
  - `tiles in // why ?`

`Tiles in` should not be called again as the event is `one()`. And the documentation says "The `.replaceWith()` method removes all data and event handlers associated with the removed nodes." So I don't know.

Comment: You can use boolean value to enter the function and then set it to false inside the function.

Comment: You're attaching two `.one()` events.. so what you expect else ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found it myself after logging the event that was fired.

https://jsfiddle.net/uhz6Ly0s/8/

```
$('#tiles').addClass(tiles_in).one(animation_end, function(event) {
    log('tiles in, event=' + event.type);
});
```

The first event is `animationend`, and the second is `webkitAnimationEnd`. For some reasons, the second one is fired at the end of the click event.

Answer (score 3):

> why ?

A call to `.one()` is within first `.one()` event handler where the the event is attached to the same selector `#tiles`

Comment: Yes, but this code `$('#tiles').addClass(tiles_out).one(animation_end, function() ...` which is the second call to `.one()` is called only once (we can see that by the log "Tile out". So why is it firing twice? I don't get it.

Comment: _"So why is it firing twice? I don't get it."_ Which portion of code are you referencing?

Comment: The function that is called by `.one()` on line 24. Sorry if I am not clear.